# Como fazer requisição de arquivo externo NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Como faço pra requisitar um arquivo externo com o NodeJS?
No caso seria um XML...
http://179.127.4.122:8449/played.html?sid=1&type=xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu pode fazer o seguinte, usar o modulo **http** para dar um **get** e converter o **path** em **xml** para uma **objeto**.
Criei como uma **promise** assim podes usar **await** em uma function **async** para esperar o get.

```
const http = require('http');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
const concat = require('concat-stream');

parser.on('error', function(err) { console.log('Parser error', err); });

const getXml = async()=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        http.get('http://179.127.4.122:8449/played.html?sid=1&type=xml', function(resp) {
            resp.on('error', function(err) {
                reject(err)
            })
            resp.pipe(concat(function(buffer) {
                const str = buffer.toString();
                parser.parseString(str, function(err, result) {
                    if(err){
                        reject(err);
                    }else{
                        console.log(result);
                        resolve(result);
                    }

                });
            }));

        });
    })
}

//export default getXml


async function init(){
    const data = await getXml()
    console.log(data);
}
init()
```

> [Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js)

Comment: Muito obrigado, você é um anjo na minha vida hahaha s2

Comment: Opa tamo ai, não esquece de marca como resposta certa, abraço.